# netty differentiate client tcp from tls connection

Tags: ssl, netty

I am writing a netty server. The first thing in the channelpipeline is a sslhandler, and the last thing is app level handler.

```
//note that sslCtx is instantiated before this part of code'
// SslHandler
pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
...
// Application handler
pipeline.addLast(new MyHandler());
```

The client may initiate a TCP or TLS connection. 
- In case of TCP, I want to log that it's only a TCP connection from peer X, and stop processing further.
- In case of TLS, I want to log that it's a TLS connection from peerX with Y ciphersuite, and Z protocol version, and move onto the application handler.

Is it even possible using netty?